# how commenting the following lines of code, can change the behviour of the previous ones?

Tags: c++

**NOTE:** I do believe that this is not an openCV related problem but since the error occurred using this library it might be a point of interest.

In the following code, by giving the wrong parameter as **cascade_name**, the *load* function throws an exception which is expected.
The interesting point is that by commenting the two following lines after catch block, the code would not throw any exception at all.

my question is, how such a thing is possible at all?!

```
cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );
cv::CascadeClassifier c;
try
{
    c.load( std::string("") );
}catch(...)
{
    cout << "Exception";
}
cv::FileStorage fs( std::string(cascade_name), cv::FileStorage::READ );
bool t2 = fs.isOpened();
bool t = c.empty();
if ( cascade == 0 )
    return -1;
return 0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, but it's possible that your compiler has done some optimization which moved those lines up so they are called before the try...catch block.

Comment: Its not. Show us what you added to the code to get the change in behavior.

Comment: to Niki: the Optimization is off.

Comment: to Martin: I added nothing. just commenting the two following lines after __catch__ block. and keeping everything else.

Comment: This has seemed to happen to me once or twice. Generally because I had failed to save some changes before the first (uncommented) test run (meaning that the "changed behavior" was relative two versions ago, not one), or because my build system was doing something dumb (causing the same situation). Accordingly I suggest re-testing *very* carefully and paying careful attention to what your build system does. If the problem persists, try to find a minimal complete program the exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Where does it throw the exception?  Does cvLoad throw the exception when you don't comment the lines?  Or does it throw the exception when you're trying to instantiate fs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the circumstances/assumptions about the program in general: it's possible, given the right set of circumstances.

For example:

You are running this function from multiple threads, and inside the openCV library the FileStorage object interacts (shares variables, etc.) with the CascadeClassifier object. The code path in one thread causes the other thread to error on the ::load method.

The times which I have seen things like this are (in order of likelihood):
- The compiler didn't rebuild with changes properly
- You didn't run the code you expected
- The addition of lines caused some problems with multi-threaded synchronization (either in your code, or inside the library)
- The addition code caused timings to change, which caused errors

Hope that helps.